# How to remove/adjust Title in the Home.aspx with SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am looking for a way to modify the title in my Home page (/SiteAssets/Home.aspx) as removing a "New" word with SharePoint 2010. I have edited in the `v4.master` page. However, it did not affect to my Home page. Besides that, I cannot find any file that has the code. Please take a look at an image below. Please let me know if I miss something to do for that change.

```
<td style="color:#185591;font-size:2.0em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,sans-serif">
    <marquee>
        Welcome to the portal
    </marquee>
</td>
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find the solution to solve issue. This requires you to have or install the SharePoint Designer. After making some changes with any page, you would like to public these changes to the Homepage as my desire, just simply do it as 2-step below:

1. Select a master page such as `v4.master`
2. Click on `Set as Default`
3. Click your result

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Go to `site settings` (click the cog in the top right hand corner and then site settings) and then click `Title, description and logo` under `Look and Feel`. The title that you're trying to change will be in there.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it was `Portal Intranet Site` and that is not the one that I would like to make any change.